# Is explict git gc needed on git on file share?

Tags: git

We are a development team who have our central repository on a windows file share.

One of our developers mistakenly pushed a very large number of commits on a branch. After that, we removed that branch from the central repository, but obviously that does not really remove the commits.

Since it is a just file share, there is no process on the file server that automatically runs `git gc`.

Do we need to run `git gc` explicitly on the central repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no process for your local repositories either.
`git gc` is not run by a background service. It is run automatically by the client after certain commands like `commit` or `push` when a certain threshold of objects that should be removed is reached.

Comment: Ok, but since nobody normally runs any git commands on the file server, then I need to run `git gc` explicitly there?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn: You do run commands on the server, namely when you do a `git push`.

Comment: So, to be absolutely clear, `git push` will, when necessary, run `git gc` on the remote repository that I am pushing *to*?

Answer (score 2):

Like Daniel said, the fact the repository is on a shared filesystem is nothing special to Git: it's the same as if this repo was located on a regular filesystem.  Hence there's no server but just a bunch of "client-side" Git processes accessing the same repository.

That is, this case is no really different from the case of a "normal" local repository typically only ever operated upon by a single developer.

As the [`git-gc` manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) states Git does perform certain checks on the repository by means of running `git gc --auto` which might detect the GC is needed and perform a it.

So...

1. `git gc --auto` will be spawned automatically by a Git process run by one of your developers operating on that repository.  This will happen all by itself.

   The precise Git operation which might trigger this is not explicitly specified in the documentation.  I think this is because there's no sense codifying this (this sort of GC is supposed to be fast and transparent anyway).
2. I see no reason why you would abstrain from running `git gc --aggressive` by hand to reclaim the free space.

   You must keep in mind though that if you have reflog enabled, you will probably want to

   - Make sure the reflog is emptied (via `git reflog expire --all` or a more fine-grained method like manually deleting only the required entries from it).
   - There's no other lingering refs (branches or tags) pointing to that unwanted history.

   Also note that while Git should properly serialize all access to the repository and employ "create + atomic rename" operations when manipulating objects, I would ask the devs to not access the repository while garbage collection is being performed on it.

P.S.
You might find [this thread](http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?group=gmane.comp.version-control.git&article=213780) interesting to read, and in particular [this post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/122670) that discussion refers to.

Answer (score 0):

**wrong answer** read the comments.

`git gc` removes unreachable objects that have been staged (with `git add`.)  I don't think it will ever remove a committed file.

Comment: `git gc` certainly removes commits that are not reachable via any branch or tag.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Interesting, didn't know that.  I'll leave the answer so people who didn't know that either can learn something :)